# how to convert this .bat (windows) to .sh (linux-Centos)

Tags: java, windows, terminal, centos

I have the following code within .bat and it works fine on Windows

*** @java -classpath ..\QVDReader.jar;..\lib\opencsv-2.3.jar;..\lib\jdbm-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ExampleQVDReader .\QVD\Customer.qvd .\CSV\Customer.csv ";" pause ***

Summary, it's  a library, that convert QVD file to CSV (without problem). But when I want to try it in a Centos Server, in terminal it's wrong, and I don't know why, I used this

***java -classpath ../QVDReader.jar;../lib/opencsv-2.3.jar;../lib/jdbm-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ExampleQVDReader ./QVD/Customer.qvd ./CSV/Customer.csv ";"***

I need execute it the same in Linux, any ideas?

Greetings.

Comment: What are you asking for?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what shell you're using, but I'll assume it's an `sh` variant, in which semicolons `;` are special characters that separate commands. So:

```
java -classpath ../QVDReader.jar;../lib/opencsv-2.3.jar;../lib/jdbm-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ExampleQVDReader ./QVD/Customer.qvd ./CSV/Customer.csv ";"
```

Is broken up into multiple commands at each semicolon, to this:

```
java -classpath ../QVDReader.jar
../lib/opencsv-2.3.jar
../lib/jdbm-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ExampleQVDReader ./QVD/Customer.qvd ./CSV/Customer.csv ";"
```

To treat the semicolons literally, put the argument in single quotes:

```
java -classpath '../QVDReader.jar;../lib/opencsv-2.3.jar;../lib/jdbm-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ExampleQVDReader ./QVD/Customer.qvd ./CSV/Customer.csv ';'
```

You can use double-quotes too, but be aware of [the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).